# optimize query with fulltext index in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, optimization

I have a column inside my mysql table that has a fulltext index and I need to make a query in which I get all the rows that do not have a specific word or those that start with those letters, so I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE NOT MATCH(title) AGAINST('Do*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Technically this query works, but does it perform a full scan to my table, so is there another approach to be able to perform this query taking advantage of the index and not finishing with a total scan to my table?

Comment: Which Engine is the table using?  Provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft%';`

Comment: @RickJames using InnoDB

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but you could try:  `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.